# Micronaut Read data base connection string from file Groovy code

Tags: micronaut

Currently I am setting database connection information in the `application.yaml` file. For production deployment I need to read the database connection string from file.

in Gitter I got the tip to use `micronaut.config.files` value, but its not working.

I defined DB connection values in `dbinfo.properties` file, then update `build.gradle` file to like this.

```
run {
    environment('micronaut.environments','dev')
    environment 'micronaut.config.files', 'C:\\shared\\application.dev.properties'    
}
```

in `application.yaml`

```
dataSource:
  url: ${DBURL}
  dbCreate: create-update
  pooled: true
  jmxExport: true
  driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  username: ${DBUSER}
  password: ${DBPASSWORD}
```

when I run its giving below error message.

```
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Could not resolve placeholder ${DBURL} in value: ${DBURL}
```

Is there an example code to read data base connection string from file Micronaut  Groovy code?

Thanks

SR

**Update: 2/26/19**

I updated `build.gradle` file like this still same error.

```
run {
    systemProperty('micronaut.environments','dev')
    systemProperty('micronaut.config.files', 'C:\\shared\\application.dev.properties')
}
```

from `Application.grooy` file

```
class Application {
    static void main(String[] args) {      
        String filename=System.properties['micronaut.config.files']
        File f= new File(filename)
        if( f.exists()){
            println "File found: $filename"
            println f.text
        } else{
            println "file not found : $filename"
        }
        Micronaut.run(Application)
    }
}
```

**Error message**

```
19:31:49.925 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [dev]
19:31:50.700 [main] INFO  i.m.c.h.g.HibernateDatastoreFactory - Starting GORM for Hibernate
19:31:50.925 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Could not resolve placeholder ${DBURL} in value: ${DBURL}
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Could not resolve placeholder ${DBURL} in value: ${DBURL}
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1040)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:201)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2034)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:156)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:143)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:67)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:274)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:260)
    at webapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:30)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Could not resolve placeholder ${DBURL} in value: ${DBURL}
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1335)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1902)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1543)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1038)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not resolve placeholder ${DBURL} in value: ${DBURL}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing environment variables with system properties

```
run {
    systemProperty('micronaut.environments','dev')
    systemProperty('micronaut.config.files', 'C:\\shared\\application.dev.properties')  
}
```

EDIT: The above will cause the file to be a property source in the application, however it won't supply environment variables like DBURL. It doesn't make sense to attempt to use a configuration file to supply those values.

Either supply those values with environment variables directly, or remove the values from config and allow the imported configuration file to provide them.

For example, remove `dataSource.url` from `application.yml` and then set `dataSource.url=someurl` in `C:\\shared\\application.dev.properties`

Comment: updated the gradle file, still its not picking up DBURL value, any tips?